# Reg Date need to be passed in request body with specific format

Tags: java, date

I am facing problem in passing date while calling remote rest service.They accept date in format 2016-11-05T12:01:01.000Z.
I need to populate this in their time field which is of type Date.How to pass date object so that server can get date in above format.Server rejects date in any other format.Can anybody help here ?

I used below approach but it did not help

```
SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                                    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
sdformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
try {                  
    transferRequest.setTime(sdformat.parse(sdformat.format(new Date())));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Regards
Gaurav Kaushik

Comment: What exception or error are you getting?

Comment: 400 Bad Request I am getting.

Comment: 400 is for validation failure, how are you sure that this field is causing the issue?

Comment: I have code in debugging mode.What request is getting passed to server when I paste same in postman I get same 400 error as code is giving me...but when I change only date in postman then I get successful reponse...time field is getting passed as below even after above changes

"time":1486974834779

Comment: what is `transferRequest`? Is is one of your classes that later on gets serialized?

Comment: yes...correct....this is the class which  later get deserialized.

Comment: you are creating a formatted string with `sdformat.format` and then you parse it again into a `Date` and pass that as an argument. Can you set the field to be `String`? Otherwise, the formatting you performed is in vain. If not and you want to keep the field as `Date`, you should add your code for serializing this class

Comment: Thanks Christ for response.Can you bit elaborate on the approach you told about "you should add your code for serializing this class" because I cant use it as String as model jars I am using is provided by service owners.

Answer (score 1):

Change the time field in transferRequest to String and try below code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
sdformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));  

transferRequest.setTime(sdformat.format(new Date()));
```

Or, if you are using Jackson to to serialize data then in TransferRequest class use the following code to set the pattern.

```
@JsonFormat (shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
private Date time;
```

And then, just set a new date in the code where you are setting the time and jackson will automatically parse the date in given format

```
transferRequest.setTime(new Date());
```

For Spring based global message converter, use the following code in your configuration class.

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    myObjectMapper.setDateFormat(df);

    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response but this I cant do.sdformat.format(new Date()) returns string.I used parse to return date object.
time field should be populated with date object,

Comment: Thanks Avinash.Can you tell me how I can do this in code.I am using 3 rd party poja jar which I am not able to change.

Comment: If you cant edit your pojo then the options are very limited. If you are using spring with jackson then you can use global message convertor but that will impact all the date fields. See the updated answer